# Hibernate Eclipse Oxygen: Could not load AnnotationConfiguration

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, reverse-engineering, eclipse-oxygen

I've been tossing and turning to solve this issue but have not been lucky. Searched around and seems to be going back to the same posts and google searches and im not going anywhere near resolving this.

As you can see the screen shot below, its saying "Could not load AnnotationConfiguration" and I do not know why. The error shows up when I add my hibernate.cfg.xml under "Configuration file". Does the DTD something to do with it? I already added annotations in pom.xml. I wanted to do a Reverse Engineering to generate the model classes from the database.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ocPm.png)

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.cabrera.ebookr</groupId>
    <artifactId>ebookr</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts-taglib -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0.CR2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC -->
    <!--        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" -->
    <!--        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd"> -->
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC 
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" 
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd" >
    <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password">test</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ebookr</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username">webuser</property>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

I don't know if this helps also, maybe some other post, but just to give a bit of details, I was not able to create the hibernate.cfg.xml through eclipse as well because some error occurs, I figured,I'll just create it manually, not much difference right? the error was:

```
 Unhandled event loop exception .ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
```

Anyway, hope someone could help.